# Is it possible to see what links are clicked on a particular page without using GTM

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have a page with a lot of links. I would like to determine if it is worth keeping all of them or removing those that users don't click on. So I would like to see what links are clicked on a page. Is this possible without Google Tag Manager?

Answer (score 0):

You can set an event on click on each link with code in page, without GTM, so you can use i.e. a JavaScript function onclick.

See the documentation for event syntax (for gtag.js): https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events